# Bijective local isometry to global isometry

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, differential-topology, metric-geometry

Suppose that I have a bijective local isometry $f: X \rightarrow Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are length spaces. Can I show that $f$ is a global isometry? My thought is to consider a path $\gamma$ from $x$ to $y$ in $X$ and look at a subdivision $(t_1, \ldots, t_n)$ of $\gamma$. Then map the subdivision $(t_1, \ldots t_n)$ to a subdivision of $f(\gamma)$ in $Y$. For a sufficiently fine subdivision each consecutive pair of points should be in the same chart on $Y$. Then the sum of the lengths should be the same in the two spaces so $f$ is an isometry. Can anyone help me formalize this a bit?

Answer (score 4):

Your argument can be firmed up to show that $f$ preserves the lengths of curves.  This in turn implies that $f$ is *nonexpanding*, i.e. $d'(f(x_1),f(x_2))\leq d(x_1,x_2)$. But without knowing that $f^{-1}$ is continuous, it's conceivable that there's some path in $Y$ from $f(x_1)$ to $f(x_2)$ which is not the image of a path in $X$ and has a shorter length than all such paths. That would stop $f$ from being an isometry. We can show that a bijective local isometry is a global isometry if and only if $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

By *length space*, I assume you mean a metric space whose induced arc-length metric agrees with the original metric (which, in particular, implies that the space is path-connected). And by *local isometry*, I assume you mean a map $f:(X,d) \to (Y,d')$ such that every point $x \in X$ has a neighborhood $U$ in which $d'(f(x_1),f(x_2))=d(x_1,x_2)$ for all $x_1,x_2 \in U$.

**Claim 1.** *A local isometry between length spaces preserves the lengths of curves.*

*Proof.* Let $\gamma:[0,1] \to X$ be a path from $x_0=\gamma(0)$ to $x_1=\gamma(1)$. Given $\epsilon>0$, we can find a subdivision $t_0<\cdots<t_n$ such that $$\sum_{i =1}^n d'(f(\gamma(t_i)),f(\gamma(t_{i+1})))<L_{d'}(f\circ \gamma)+\epsilon.$$
We can cover the image of $\gamma$ in $X$ with open sets on which $f$ is an isometry. This image is compact, so we can extract a finite subcover. It's straightforward to see that we can add terms to the subdivision $t_0<\cdots<t_n$ until each interval $[t_i,t_{i +1}]$ is mapped into one of the open sets on which $f$ is an isometry. (For example, pull back the finite cover and use the Lebesgue Number Lemma.) By adding even more terms, we ensure that 
 $$\sum_{i =1}^n d(\gamma(t_i),\gamma(t_{i+1}))<L_{d}( \gamma)+\epsilon.$$
Now we have 
\begin{align*}
L_d(\gamma)&< \epsilon+\sum_{i =1}^n d(\gamma(t_i),\gamma(t_{i+1}))\\
&=\epsilon+\sum_{i =1}^n d'(f(\gamma(t_i)),f(\gamma(t_{i+1})))\\
&\leq L_{d'}(f\circ \gamma)+\epsilon.
\end{align*}
We also have
\begin{align*}
L_{d}(\gamma) &>\sum_{i =1}^n d(\gamma(t_i),\gamma(t_{i +1}))-\epsilon\\
&=\sum_{i =1}^n d'(f(\gamma(t_i)),f(\gamma( t_{i +1})))-\epsilon\\
&\geq L_{d'}(f\circ \gamma)-\epsilon,
\end{align*}
as desired.

**Claim 2.** *If a bijective local isometry between length spaces has a continuous inverse, then it is a global isometry.*

*Proof.* Since $f^{-1}$ is continuous, each neighborhood $U$ on which $f$ is an isometry is carried to an open set $(f^{-1})^{-1}(U)=f(U)$. Then it is easy to see that $f^{-1}$ is an isometry on $f(U)$. It follows that $f^{-1}$ is also a local isometry, hence preserves the lengths of curves. This means $f$ respects the arc-length metric. And since the arc-length metric agrees with the original metric, we conclude that $f$ is a global isometry. $\square$

Comment: Oddly, some content was lost from this answer when I posted it. I'll fill it back in tomorrow.

Comment: OP assumes that f is a local isometry. With the usual definition of a local isometry, it is clear that the inverse map is continuous. Of course, maybe OP only requires f to be a distance preserving map on small balls, this indeed does not ensure continuity of the inverse map. If OP's notion agrees with your definition then there are very simple examples of bijective local isometrics which do not have a continuous inverse.